# update joind table with new data

Tags: mysql, sql

im staring working with SQL and find a challenge.

I have 2 tables joined, in T1 address_id a FK form address

T1

```
id(PK) | name | email | fax | address_id(FK)
01     |  n1  |  n2   | n3  |   0
```

table address

```
id(PK) | adress | country 
0      |    nd  | nd
```

im trying to add some data to the `address` table and update the FK on `T1` table with the key from the table with the new data

i was trying this but it didn't work

```
INSERT  INTO adress (adress, country,) 
VALUES ("um","dois")  

UPDATE  T1 
Join    adress 
SET     T1.address_id = adress.id 
where   T1.id = 01:
```

i tried with 2 or 3 sql queries but it didn't work.

how i can do this?

When I add a new record to table `address` i want to update table `T1` with the key of the new record from table `address`.

Comment: Where did `morada_idmorada` column come from in your `UPDATE`? Also you need a condition to `JOIN` the tables.

Comment: `morada_idmorada ` was misspelled but now its fixed , im doing this em PT, where i need to add that JOIN?

Comment: If that is a column from a table not posted in you question, please add the table definition and tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: ist done, check my answer

Comment: What DBMS are you using, Mysql or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO address
(`address`, `country`)
VALUES
('um', 'dois')
;

UPDATE  T1
SET     T1.address_id = (select last_insert_id()) 
where   T1.id = 01;
```

Take a look here for some explanations about `last_insert_id()` :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id